# How can I copy images to my camera for viewing?

Tags: canon, metadata

I'd like to copy an image from the web to my camera (Canon S95) and view it on my camera's screen, sort of a poor man's iPad.  I tried renaming the file but the camera reports "Incompatible JPEG".

From reading online, it seems that I need the proper EXIF information in the file.  Is there a way for me to take an image off the web and add the EXIF information?  Ideally, the process would be automatic and work in batch.

The reason is that I want to save the weight of maps while traveling or hiking.  I'll bring my camera anyway so it might as well hold images of the maps, too.

Comment: Search for Exiftool, but I have to admit that seems like a really odd thing to do...

Comment: Many cameras (including my Pentax K-r) are picky about the EXIF structures in the image file.  If the image does not contain certain EXIF structures, or contains unrecognized EXIF fields, the camera will not display the image.  I'm not sure why, but it may be to prevent problems from occurring when parsing a JPEG header with unrecognized EXIF fields.  Related on [su]: http://superuser.com/questions/293810/rotated-pictures-on-sd-card-cant-be-displayed-on-my-camera

Comment: Take a picture of the map from the camera you wish to carry :-)

Answer (score 6):

It is probably be easier to go backwards. Start with an image from your camera and paste the images you download onto it, saving the result as a new file after each paste. This can be done in Photoshop Elements or other cheap image-processing applications and *probably* automated with more advanced software.

Honestly for the work and effort, you should truly consider putting down $10-20 on a [photo keychain](https://www.google.ca/search?q=digital%20photo%20keychain&hl=en&sa=X&site=webhp&prmd=imvns&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&ei=9DRnT9TKIYLKgQe7mbTvAg&ved=0CIwBELAE&biw=1452&bih=1452) which is a tiny JPEG viewer that fits in your pocket.

Comment: The reason that I want to do this is to put maps that I download onto my camera so that I can view them and zoom in while on holiday without haven't to carry all the maps, just my camera which I was bringing anyway.  So I don't know if a photo keychain would work, but I'll try your idea.

Comment: Not that I have the same camera but I tried this before and zooming it does not work. On my Fuji, when I put a photo from somewhere else, the image shows with a small 'Gift' icon but it can only be seen as a thumbnail, no zoom, no EXIF, no histograms.

Comment: you can additionally take photos of your maps with your camera (assuming you have paper ones) :P

Comment: Photos of maps is what I've been doing so far.

Answer (score 4):

I have S95 too and I was experiencing the same problem.

- Both the width and height of the image must be multiplies of 8.
- The name of the file must correspond with the naming on the SD card (eg. IMG_0123.jpg).

For the record I saved the image in Photoshop CS6 beta (using "Save for Web...") as normal JPG with 80 quality without progressive or optimized option checked, I also unchecked the  sRGB color space option. I did not messed with EXIF data at all.

Comment: Cannot thank you enough for this "multiples of 8" observation: I couldn't view *some* cropped images on either my 600D or Selphy photo printer and nothing in the EXIF seemed remotely wrong. It's exactly this multiples of 8 that finally fixes it. I've spent *years* wondering what's going on!  Only wish I could upvote you more :-)