# Why can't I view an edited image on my camera?

Tags: metadata, photo-editing, image-review

*This question is an extension of [How can I copy images to my camera for viewing?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/21472/how-can-i-copy-images-to-my-camera-for-viewing).*

When I take a picture on my camera, edit it on my computer, and send it back to my camera, my camera cannot display the image.  Why is this so?

This applies to many makes and models of cameras and appears to be related to the Exif data in the image file.  Why does the camera need to be picky about the Exif data in the image?  Is there a technical reason the Exif structures need to be in a certain format?

Comment: When you say "send it back to my camera", what exactly does that mean? Are you saving your edits to a CF or SD card, and putting that back in your camera? Generally speaking, images flow OUT of the camera...there is generally little reason to put them back IN.

Comment: Yes.  I do expect to be able to view images on my camera, as a simple means of showing images to others, though they do get stored on the computer as well.

Comment: What format do you save the images in? If you save it in any other format than JPEG I wouldn't be surprised if they didn't display.

Comment: The format is JPEG.

Comment: When editing are you resizing your pictures?

Comment: No, images are not being resized.

Comment: What are the names of the images you put back onto the memory card? Cameras usually require that images conform to a specific filename format, and reside in a specific folder.

Comment: The images retain their original name in their original folder, or are changed such that they comply with the [Design rule for Camera File system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_rule_for_Camera_File_system).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the camera but on the ones I tried it only partially works.

In particular my Fuji F300EXR shows the image with a 'Gift' icon, complete with ribbons :) and show the preview but zoom in or EXIF display is not possible.

The Sony I had (Don't remember the model HX-something) did not even like me renaming its own photos without modification! In this case there were plenty of non-image files and directories created by the camera, so I assume the camera has an index of photos, maybe even with the previews cached separately somewhere.

Some cameras do not like different EXIF but some use other data to index the card and if you put a photo that does not match, then is it simply not seen.